# How does Scala know the difference between "def foo" and "def foo()"?

Tags: scala

I know about the usage difference between empty-parameter and parameterless methods in scala, and my question pertains to the class file generated.  When I look at these two classes in javap, they look exactly the same:

```
class Foo {
  def bar() = 123;
}


class Foo {
  def bar = 123;
}
```

But when I look at them in scalap, they accurately reflect the parameter lists.  Where in the class file is scalac making this distinction known?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the .class file, there is a class file attribute called `ScalaSig`, which contains all of the extra information needed by Scala. It's not really readable by humans, but it is there:

```
$ javap -verbose Foo.class
const #195 = Asciz      ScalaSig;
const #196 = Asciz      Lscala/reflect/ScalaSignature;;
const #197 = Asciz      bytes;
const #198 = Asciz      ^F^A!3A!^A^B^A^S\t\tb)^[7f^Y^Vtw\r^^5DQ^V^\7.^Z:^K^E\r!^
Q^A^B4jY^VT!!^B^D^B^UM^\^W\r\1tifdWMC^A^H^....
```

See also [How is the Scala signature stored?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/945) and [scala.reflect.ScalaSignature](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/reflect/ScalaSignature.java), which isn't very interesting :-)

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason, -verbose never jumped out at me from the javap manpage, and as you said, it isn't the most human-readable thing in the world :)