# Where does Scala store information that cannot be represented in Java?

Tags: scala, bytecode

There are some constructs that don't have equivalents in java. Examples would be

- named parameters
- instance private members

Where/How does Scala store the information necessary for this stuff (some kind of flag in the first case, the parameter names in the second case?

If I get it right this has to get stored in the byte code, since it works even if I just have a compiled library without the source code!?

Comment: [Not quite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10130106/334519) a duplicate, but close. What you're looking for is the `ScalaSig` attribute, which is in fact in the byte code.

Comment: Thank you. Wanna make that an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information is captured in an annotation named `ScalaSig` in the class file (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130403/334519) for an example).

You can view the (not very human-friendly) annotation with `javap -verbose`, or [parse it](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/scalap/index.html#scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigParser$) using an internal API, but in general [neither should be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986402/334519).